need example Matlab codes(algorithms) of connection weights and sensitivity analysis methods of determining variable importance
need example Matlab codes(algorithms) of connection weights method and sensitivity analysis method for determining the input variables' importance in my pattern recognition NN.
have Garson's algorithm but its results are not reproducible and does not seem valid.
please share an example Matlab algorithm for these two.
